# Pytket's SquashTK1 pass changes symbolic parameters of gates into complicated expressions

Tags: quantum-gate, compiling, pytket

For a very simple circuit, such as

```python
from pytket.circuit import Circuit, fresh_symbol

a = fresh_symbol("a")
circ = Circuit(1)
circ.X(0)
circ.Ry(a,0)
```

the circuit that results from applying a SquashTK1 pass:

```python
from pytket import passes

passes.SquashTk1().apply(circ)
```

has a very complicated expression for it's parameters:

$$
-2 \operatorname{atan}_2\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2}\right).
$$

In the end, this expression is the arctan of a tan and it may be used as a replacement of taking the modulus, but I wonder if anyone has any idea why this occurs.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to quantum computing stack exchange :). Just to clarify... are asking why the trigometric expression is fairly complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Squashing symbolic gates with optimisation passes like [SquashTK1](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/passes.html#pytket.passes.SquashTK1) frequently leads to lengthy trigometric expresions. See the [pytket user manual](https://cqcl.github.io/pytket/manual/manual_circuit.html#symbolic-circuits) for some background.

However in this case its possible to simplify the symbolic unitary with [sympy.simplify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#id1).

```python
from pytket.circuit import Circuit, fresh_symbol
from pytket.utils.symbolic import circuit_to_symbolic_unitary
from pytket import passes

a = fresh_symbol("a")
circ = Circuit(1)
circ.X(0)
circ.Ry(a, 0)

passes.SquashTK1().apply(circ) # squash two gates to a single TK1 gate

circuit_to_symbolic_unitary(circ) # view complicated unitary
```

The output looks like this

[image]

However we can make this look much nicer.

```python
from sympy import simplify

simplify(circuit_to_symbolic_unitary(circ))
```

We get the simplier matrix below

[image]

I hope this helps. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @Diego Olvera
It occurs to me that the answer I provided above maybe doesn't quite address the question you asked as you asked about complicated expressions in the gate parameters rather than the circuit of the unitary. I think the truth is that squashing usually leads to compilated expressions. Maybe you could look into constructing a `CustomPass` in pytket that iterates through the circuit and simplifies expressions using `sympy.simplify` but this could get a bit tricky.